# AWS API Gateway "Unsupported method \"undefined\"" as response

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am setting up a AWS Lambda function to connect to my DynamoDB. To access it I'm also setting up an API Gateway.

The lambda seems to work when I test it. Because of this I believe the issue to be in the API gateway setup.

[image: API Gateway setup]

For the lambda I have configured the following test event:
I have configured a test event which looks like this:

```
{
  "httpMethod": "GET"
}
```

This test event gives me the following response:

```
Response:
{
  "statusCode": "200",
  "body": "{\"Items\":[{\"id\":1,\"brand\":\"Test brand\",\"title\":\"Test product\"}],\"Count\":1,\"ScannedCount\":1}",
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }
}
```

For the API Gateway I have tried with the following test:
[image: API Gateway test]

I have tried automatically creating the API Gateway in the lambda management console. Recreating the lambda and the API Gateway.

Lambda function:

```
console.log('Loading function');

const doc = require('dynamodb-doc');

const dynamo = new doc.DynamoDB();


/**
 * Demonstrates a simple HTTP endpoint using API Gateway. You have full
 * access to the request and response payload, including headers and
 * status code.
 *
 * To scan a DynamoDB table, make a GET request with the TableName as a
 * query string parameter. To put, update, or delete an item, make a POST,
 * PUT, or DELETE request respectively, passing in the payload to the
 * DynamoDB API as a JSON body.
 */
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    //console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));

    const done = (err, res) => callback(null, {
        statusCode: err ? '400' : '200',
        body: err ? err.message : JSON.stringify(res),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
    });

    switch (event.httpMethod) {
        case 'DELETE':
            dynamo.deleteItem(JSON.parse(event.body), done);
            break;
        case 'GET':
            dynamo.scan({ "TableName": "productdb" }, done);
            //dynamo.scan({"TableName":"productdb"})
            break;
        case 'POST':
            dynamo.putItem(JSON.parse(event.body), done);
            break;
        case 'PUT':
            dynamo.updateItem(JSON.parse(event.body), done);
            break;
        default:
            done(new Error(`Unsupported method "${event.httpMethod}"`));
    }
};
```

API Gateway logs from the test:

```
Execution log for request 885e5505-2212-11e9-aee0-7f024016f574
Sun Jan 27 09:04:20 UTC 2019 : Starting execution for request: 885e5505-2212-11e9-aee0-7f024016f574
Sun Jan 27 09:04:20 UTC 2019 : HTTP Method: GET, Resource Path: /
Sun Jan 27 09:04:20 UTC 2019 : Method request path: {}
Sun Jan 27 09:04:20 UTC 2019 : Method request query string: {}
Sun Jan 27 09:04:20 UTC 2019 : Method request headers: {}
Sun Jan 27 09:04:20 UTC 2019 : Method request body before transformations: 
Sun Jan 27 09:04:20 UTC 2019 : Endpoint request URI: https://lambda.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:304886708348:function:dynamoDBService/invocations
Sun Jan 27 09:04:20 UTC 2019 : Endpoint request headers: {x-amzn-lambda-integration-tag=885e5505-2212-11e9-aee0-7f024016f574, Authorization=*****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************500617, X-Amz-Date=20190127T090420Z, x-amzn-apigateway-api-id=lqhm3agxxf, X-Amz-Source-Arn=arn:aws:execute-api:eu-central-1:304886708348:lqhm3agxxf/test-invoke-stage/GET/, Accept=application/json, User-Agent=AmazonAPIGateway_lqhm3agxxf, X-Amz-Security-Token=FQoGZXIvYXdzEOH//////////wEaDFvawdYGjH/+gSI14yK9AzQFZtlDghAr2NUHIhLGWmeJkKL8sUP3L6fu0h5PtFPN7wA7hgfWMtUNHCWyGykG0g5Zs81zKx5bUGMLCMK2zuVwD4WMgBRmkx40bZYehHdeS8czOxRTbQIqwP1lfZ0d74l4MqG4g8XpigkcLACLEn6buaq37rO4WYOo+J8ecFeSpti+u+V8OON4idxxXEHiYGJEc23OwjVvf3GTr1EUscB+Lsp/nw58oCWQArUA6LLSwcnGYXYcmnPav2Xs8mJgvqnVowxxYre0N8Gca8D9XBN2Y93/qnVTsOI5nWHSUQOnwaoXSZzgBAXKrUV1S5X+UH3zQI9p [TRUNCATED]
Sun Jan 27 09:04:20 UTC 2019 : Endpoint request body after transformations: 
Sun Jan 27 09:04:20 UTC 2019 : Sending request to https://lambda.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:304886708348:function:dynamoDBService/invocations
Sun Jan 27 09:04:20 UTC 2019 : Received response. Integration latency: 17 ms
Sun Jan 27 09:04:20 UTC 2019 : Endpoint response body before transformations: {"statusCode":"400","body":"Unsupported method \"undefined\"","headers":{"Content-Type":"application/json"}}
Sun Jan 27 09:04:20 UTC 2019 : Endpoint response headers: {Date=Sun, 27 Jan 2019 09:04:20 GMT, Content-Type=application/json, Content-Length=108, Connection=keep-alive, x-amzn-RequestId=6c00229e-caa1-4d37-aeaa-7c1cbd0ddd71, x-amzn-Remapped-Content-Length=0, X-Amz-Executed-Version=$LATEST, X-Amzn-Trace-Id=root=1-5c4d7414-e52b0fba267596b50fdbb102;sampled=0}
Sun Jan 27 09:04:20 UTC 2019 : Method response body after transformations: {"statusCode":"400","body":"Unsupported method \"undefined\"","headers":{"Content-Type":"application/json"}}
Sun Jan 27 09:04:20 UTC 2019 : Method response headers: {X-Amzn-Trace-Id=Root=1-5c4d7414-e52b0fba267596b50fdbb102;Sampled=0, Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*, Content-Type=application/json}
Sun Jan 27 09:04:20 UTC 2019 : Successfully completed execution
Sun Jan 27 09:04:20 UTC 2019 : Method completed with status: 200
```

I expect the result to be the same as the test event in the lambda returns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you create an API method, you need to select the option "Use Lambda Proxy integration" in order for the `httpMethod` field, along with other information from the API Gateway, to be accessible in the `event` object in your Lambda function.

From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html):

> You can set up a Lambda proxy integration for any API method. But a
>   Lambda proxy integration is more potent when it is configured for an
>   API method involving a generic proxy resource. The generic proxy
>   resource can be denoted by a special templated path variable of
>   {proxy+}, the catch-all ANY method placeholder, or both. The client
>   can pass the input to the backend Lambda function in the incoming
>   request as request parameters or applicable payload. The request
>   parameters include headers, URL path variables, query string
>   parameters, and the applicable payload. The integrated Lambda function
>   verifies all of the input sources before processing the request and
>   responding to the client with meaningful error messages if any of the
>   required input is missing.

You can find the "Use Lambda Proxy integration" option here, on the "Create Method" screen in your API Gateway instance:

[image]

**Edit:** For reference, you can tell that the API Gateway method is not using the Lambda proxy integration because under "Integration Request" the type is "LAMBDA", but when using the Lambda proxy integration the type is "LAMBDA_PROXY".

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who couldn't get the above solutions to work, I had to change the `switch` statement for the http method that the Lambda function was originally built with

from: `switch (event.httpMethod) {`

to: `switch (event.requestContext.http.method) {`

I think V1.0 uses `event.httpMethod`? but I wasn't able to change the version in the API Gateway (message: "API Gateway managed resources are view only"). So I had to change the switch statement to match the `event` object.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the issue for HTTP API, by changing the payload format to V1.0 (under the integration details for the route).